# Why my Flutter app thinks it can send money?

Tags: flutter, dart

When going to contacts an option to send or recieve money, an app will be the default. If you click on it the app opens

This is on my device only as I have Revolut app that allows sending of money.[image]

i am not using any package which has anything to do with transferring money or can make any request like that.

Comment: Regex detecting a phone number that activates action to do money transfer on a phone number?

Comment: i am not using regex or any package related to it @Antoniossss

Answer (score 2):

Its resolve for now after a little debugging an di found that i was using some intent filters in my AndroidManifest.xml file so i removed those and which helps me resolved my problem too..